# Autocorrection with eslint's solid/event-handlers results in typescript errors

Tags: typescript, eslint, solid-js, ondoubleclick, ondblclick

I am using `solid/event-handlers` rule of `eslint-plugin-solid` with eslint.
After automatically repairing the error that occurred in `onDblClick`, it became `onDoubleClick` and an error occurred in typescript.

- Why does `eslint-plugin-solid` auto-repair `onDblClick` to `onDoubleClick`?
- How can I avoid errors in typescript?

node: 16.16.0
npm: 8.11.0
eslint: 8.26.0
eslint-plugin-solid: 0.8.0
typescript: 4.8.4

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "solid-js",
    "types": ["vite/client"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```json
{
  "root": true,
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["solid"],
  "rules": {
    "solid/event-handlers": "warn"
  }
}
```

src/App.tsx

```js
export const App = () => {
  return <div onDblClick={() => alert("hello world")}>double click me</div>;
};
```

Running `npx eslint --fix src/App.tsx` fixes it.

src/App.tsx

```js
export const App = () => {
  return <div onDoubleClick={() => alert("hello world")}>double click me</div>;
};
```

Then run `npx tsc` and you will get an error.

```
src/App.tsx:2:15 - error TS2322: Type '{ children: string; onDoubleClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Property 'onDoubleClick' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>'. Did you mean 'onDblClick'?

2   return <div onDoubleClick={() => alert("hello world")}>double click me</div>;
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they erroneously mapped `dblclick` to `DoubleClick` on [event-handlers.ts#17](https://github.com/solidjs-community/eslint-plugin-solid/blob/fe7b8da2e9ede073faf03bc97e35a34d5e841824/src/rules/event-handlers.ts#L17).

You can disable eslint for a specific line using `// eslint-disable-line` or `// eslint-disable-next-line`.